# How to get circle shape from this mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have this shape, where the from the front I don't have a problem to make into a circle using the Looptools. But the shape from the back has in between gaps which I cannot use the looptools to get a good circular shape, when I do try use the circle from the loopstools it get deformed.

[image]

2nd image from the rear of the shape. if I use the circle from the looptools it will distort the shape of the bullet sockets.
How can I get the rear to be more circular to match the front shape which has a nice circle shape?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). So you want to make the 'circular' segments more smooth, without destroying the sockets?

Comment: Hi there, yes that would be great, I also did try the looptools: relax, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need more geometry to do that.

1. Add more loopcuts to the 'circle' segments
2. Select only vertices outside the 'sockets'
3. Go *Mesh > Tranform > To Sphere* (Looptools should work too)

[image]

Comment: Ok, great thanks for the tip, always helpful!

Comment: No prob, happy modeling :)